# IK bone does not perfectly follows the target

Tags: armature, constraints

[image]

I have no idea why it behaves like that. even when i'm doing animation render, the IK is still miscalculated a lot.

Here's the render result

[image]

[image]

notice that the hand is slightly moving down from the grip, even though i parent the IK target bone to the front grip. 
the target bone follows the grip perfectly, but the IK bone is just keep glicthed up and down make it seems disconnected from the target.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Blender debug console and make sure Blender is not detecting a cyclical dependency chain in your armature.  IK constraints are the first to freak out when these are present in your model.

Answer (score 0):

- Consider adding another small low polygon mesh which  parented to the gun.  Set this mesh to No Render.
- A Cube, Sphere, Empty Controller, or Plane work well and have a known center.
- The new sphere will be the target of the IK constraint and its placement can be flexible.
- The sphere can be placed anywhere on the handle,
- Know that a mesh target will have a particular point chosen by some algorithm which will choose some average.  This average may not be exactly where you want it to be.

[image]

- In the image above, a mesh is created to be the target of IK.
- Particular vertices of a high poly mesh, a vertex group, can be a target yet I find that less flexible.

Comment: so instead of parenting the ik target directly to the grip mesh,i should use an empty (which is parented to grip) as ik target parent?